# Why is MySQL Derived Condition Pushdown Optimization not working

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Can anyone explain why MySQL Derived Condition Pushdown Optimization https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-condition-pushdown-optimization.html is not happening for this query?

```
SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT ST.SERVICE_TICKET_ID,
                 ST.SERVICE_CATEGORY_ID,
                 ST.STATUS_ID,
                 EC.BRANCH_ID,
                 ST.PRICE,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(STTPER.FIRST_NAME, ' ', STTPER.LAST_NAME ORDER BY STTPER.LAST_NAME, STTPER.FIRST_NAME SEPARATOR ', ')
          FROM SERVICE_TICKET ST
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN ELEMENT_CUSTOMER EC ON ST.CUSTOMER_ID = EC.PARTY_ID
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE_TICKET_TECHNICIAN STT
                                   ON ST.SERVICE_TICKET_ID = STT.SERVICE_TICKET_ID AND (NOT STT.INACTIVE <=> 1)
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON STTPER ON STT.TECHNICIAN_ID = STTPER.PARTY_ID
           WHERE ((ST.SERVICE_TICKET_CATEGORY_ID = 'SERVICE' AND ST.STATUS_ID <> 'SVC_TICK_DEACTIVATED'))
          GROUP BY ST.SERVICE_TICKET_ID ) REPORT
WHERE (((REPORT.BRANCH_ID IN ('10081') AND REPORT.SERVICE_CATEGORY_ID = '10080')))
```

It seems to meet the qualification for optimization

> When the derived table has a `GROUP BY` and uses no window functions, an outer `WHERE` condition referencing one or more columns which are not part of the `GROUP BY` can be pushed down to the derived table as a `HAVING` condition.

The problem is definitely related to GROUP BY, because *it works when I remove it*. It doesn't matter whether I try GROUP_CONCAT() or COUNT(), so it doesn't seem to be related to the specific aggregate function.

Here's the EXPLAIN

[image]

Yes, the optimizer-switch setting for derived-condition-pushdown is 'on', as is evidenced by it working when the GROUP BY is removed.

If I can understand WHY it's not optimizing, perhaps I can craft a workaround.

Comment: Please post code, data, and **results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Can you show the EXPLAIN you get if you manually rewrite using `HAVING`, so we can see the difference you expect?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I see you are filtering by columns that are neither aggregated nor in the GROUP BY clause, but they are okay because I suppose they are functionally dependent on the column in the GROUP BY clause? Perhaps the derived condition pushdown feature doesn't work for such columns. You could experiment by replacing your condition with a condition on `SERVICE_TICKET_ID`.

Comment: @BillKarwin You are correct! It dawned on me that that could be the problem shortly after I posted. My current GROUP BY column is unique in the result set. Once I add all of the non-aggregated columns to the GROUP BY, the query is optimized as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation about derived condition pushdown covers two cases related to subqueries with aggregation:

- *"When the derived table has a GROUP BY and uses no window functions, an outer WHERE condition referencing one or more columns which are not part of the GROUP BY can be pushed down to the derived table as a HAVING condition."*

  But the example shows only references to aggregated columns.
- "When the derived table uses a GROUP BY and the columns in the outer WHERE condition are GROUP BY columns, the WHERE conditions referencing those columns can be pushed down directly to the derived table."

However, your query shows a different case: the columns you reference in the outer query are neither aggregated nor in the GROUP BY of the inner query. I assume they are functionally dependent on the column in the GROUP BY.

As you found out by experimenting, if you explicitly list these columns in your GROUP BY in the subquery, then it allows derived condition pushdown to work.

Comment: In fact, I only need to additionally GROUP BY the columns referenced in the outer WHERE, not all that are SELECTed. IIRC, there's a minor performance improvement in not grouping where not necessary.